# How can I pass a prop by child index in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to develop a generic container for React, that would work like this:

```
<PanelContainer>
    <PanelConsole />
    <PanelMemory />
    <PanelLog />
</PanelContainer>
```

I want to dynamically create a tab system within the container, this works as follows:

```
renderTabs = () => {
        return (
            <ul className="panel_tabs">
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => 
                    <li key={child.type.display_name} onClick={() => this.handleClickTab(i)}>
                        {child.type.display_name}
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

This allows me to render the tabs with the display_name property within the class. This so far works, but now I'm trying to get the click to work. I want it to work dynamically so I don't have to build specialized containers for each instance of the panel. I'd ideally like to set the property of a child in this.props.children by index, so for example:

```
this.props.children[0].props.shown = false;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with this `shown` prop? You could store the index and a boolean representing if that particular index is shown or not in the `PanelContainer` state.

Comment: I basically want a dynamic version of this: `<PanelConsole shown={this.state.selected==0} />` so that I can simply set it by ID within the PanelContainer state.

Comment: You can have a look at the implementation of `seapig` library. You may find some hints for how to solve your problem. https://github.com/enkidevs/seapig

Comment: I know what you are looking to do after reading this a few times. If no one answers this question by the time I wake up tomorrow, I will answer it, and include a working codepen for you. Cheers.

Comment: @euvs Looks like quite a lot of code to go through - but I think the answer is a good solution.

Comment: @Daniel So far I think the answer is a good solution but I'm worried about having too much markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `React.Children.map` and `React.cloneElement` works for you:

```
render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const tabs = this._renderTabs();
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, id) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { shown: this.state.shows[i] }));

    return (
         <div>
             <div>{tabs}</div>
             <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Won't this result in additional markup/Dom elements? But it looks like a decent solution otherwise.

Comment: I don't know how you want to render children and tab into DOM. I just add a demo so that you can easily get the idea.